# $_POST is empty if empty json value is sent

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

Here's how I'm sending:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/api/task/${taskId}`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({test: []}),
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Or like this (tried both):

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/api/task/${taskId}`,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {test: []}
});
```

On the receiving end, if I access $_POST, it is empty. If I access file_get_contents('php://input'), then it contains my json.

What's going on here?

Comment: why are there ticks `\`` around `/api/task/${taskId}`? Shouldn't those be regular quotes? `'`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Newer JavaScript allows string interpolation, this is valid. See [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @tadman Oh, I didn't know that; I stand corrected then. I'll leave my comment(s) for future visitors who also may not know then, thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, the first time I saw them I was really confused too, but they're a thing and they're pretty nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` will only contain urlencoded variables submitted as part of a form. Here you're posting JSON data not as a variable, but as a payload.

As such you'll need to read it out of the request input as you would a file upload.

Comment: `fopen('php://input')` etc. if I am not mistaken.

Comment: So I guess my real issue is that form encoded doesn't support empty arrays as values?

Comment: I'd have a closer look at what's actually sent to see if they're being stripped on the sending side, or if they're being ignored on the receiving side. What you have there should be valid JSON.

Comment: its your passing the data as a string, typically  I just put `{test:[]}`

Comment: When you're posting raw JSON data these things are no longer key/value parameter pairs, so you're going to need to decode them manually.

Comment: @tadman You're right. I'd managed to conflate two separate issues. I'm going to make a new question. I'll accept this one when the timer allows.